# Insert a record in two mysql tables with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I've been trying to do this with TWO different queries, but only the first one works. PDO is new for me that's why i'm a little confuse.

```
    <?php
include 'database.php';
$nombres=$_POST['tnombres'];
$apellidos=$_POST['tapellidos'];
$carrera=$_POST['tcarrera'];
$con->beginTransaction();

try{

        // insert query
        $query = "INSERT INTO alumno (nombres,apellidos) VALUES (:nombres,:apellidos)"`;`

        // prepare query for execution
        $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

        // bind the parameters
        $stmt->bindValue(':nombres',$nombres,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':apellidos',$apellidos,PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
        $ultimo=$con->lastInsertId();

        $query = "INSERT INTO ficha (fechaingreso,carrera,alumno_id) VALUES (:fechaingreso,:carrera,:alumno_id)";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

        $fecha=  date('d-m-Y');
        $stmt->bindValue(':fechaingreso',$fecha);
        $stmt->bindValue(':carrera',$carrera);
        $stmt->bindValue(':alumnoid',$ultimo);
        $stmt->execute();

        $con->commit(); 
        echo 'Datos insertados';
        echo '<p><a href=index.php>Inicio</a></p>';
        echo "<p>Numero de ultimo registro insertado: ",$ultimo;
    }

    // show error
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $con->rollback();
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Like i said before the first query works perfectly even the capture of the id from the last record inserted works but the second query don't do what it have to.
I have this message of error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\escuela\crear.php on line 32
```

Comment: `:alumno_id` != `:alumnoid`. In the query you have one, but when it comes to binding you are using it without `_`...

Comment: thanks man. I didn't notice that little thing. I change this code several times I started using bindParam instead of bindValud, so i think i was looking a complicated answer for something very simple.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your script. In your `INSERT` you are using `alumno_id` but later you try to bind the value via `alumnoid`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ficha (fechaingreso,carrera,alumno_id) VALUES (:fechaingreso,:carrera,:alumno_id)";
```

The underscore is missing - `alumnoid` is not the same as `alumno_id`.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':alumnoid',$ultimo);
```

As @FirstOne allready mentioned it: The solution is to add or remove the `_` underscore from one of the both variables.

Comment: [Oh well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758061/insert-a-record-in-two-mysql-tables-with-pdo#comment59189587_35758061). Anyway, fix it by either removing the `_` in one or adding it in the other...

Comment: Why don't you posted your own answer as an answer?